# tf.ones_like(tensor) with a specific index set to 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to mimic tf.ones_like() where "Given a single tensor (tensor), this operation returns a tensor of the same type and shape as tensor with all elements set to 1." except I want to specify a certain column index to be set to 0.  For example, I want the first column to be all 0

if Given `tensor = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]` then I would like to return `[[0,1,1], [0,1,1]]` if I specify the first column. Is there any way to do this with tensorflow operations?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, from [Variable helper functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops#Variable_helper_functions) only the `assign` can be of any reasonable help in cases like this. If you would not choose to let numpy out, I can suggest this code:

```
t = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
v = tf.Variable(t)
t = np.ones_like(t)
t[:,0] = 0
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(v.assign(t)))
```